# sqlstate[42s22]: column not found: 1054 unknown column 'description' in 'field list'

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

```php
<?php

namespace Database\Factories;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory;

class ListingFactory extends Factory
{
    /**
     * Define the model's default state.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function definition()
    {
        return [
              'title' => $this->faker->sentence(),
              'tags' => 'laravel, api, backend',
              'company' => $this->faker->company(),
              'email' => $this->faker->companyEmail(),
              'website' => $this->faker->url(),
              'location' => $this->faker->city(),
              'description' => $this->faker->paragraph(2)
        ];
    }
}
```

this is the error it brings:

sqlstate[42s22]: column not found: 1054 unknown column 'description' in 'field list' (sql: insert into `listings` (`title`, `tags`, `company`, `location`, `email`, `website`, `description`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values

Comment: And how should we know? There is probly something wrong in your sql query and/or your database

Comment: What is the full error message? The message is telling you that it does NOT know one of the column references, so cross check the columns with what is trying to be used with the faker vs. what the table actually has.

Comment: paul T i have made corection to the question check it out

Comment: Without showing the table structure, there is no way of answering this question. The error message is pretty clear, the column doesnt exist in the table.

Comment: Please provide the migration for the table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing it from the migration, please add

```
 
$schema->string('description')->nullable()
```

inside your database migration file located in database/migrations/<date_and_table_name>.php and run `php artisan migrate:refresh` or equivalent database migration command again.